# Database storage and retrieval

Tags: android

I want to store my database file in drawable folder and then create its back up in SD-Card. While trying to do this i am findind problem in what path to be given for drawable folder. I am doing this:

try {

```
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            //db = openOrCreateDatabase("demodatabase.sqlite",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
    currentDBPath = "//drawable//demodatabase.sqlite";



   db=openOrCreateDatabase(uri.toString(), 0, null);
        System.out.println("====="+ currentDBPath);
        backupDBPath = "{demodatabase.sqlite}";

        File currentDB = new File(data,  currentDBPath);

        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {

        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();

        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

        src.close();

        dst.close();

        }

        } }catch (Exception e) {}
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you would put such files not in the drawable folder but in your assets folder and you can get an input stream to these files just by using

```
context.getAssets().open("demodatabase.sqlite")
```

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception, the context is not taking values...why so?]

Comment: Are you using the SQLiteOpenHelper class as super class?

Comment: then you can just use getAssets().open("demodatabase.sqlite") because the activity itself is the context

Comment: db=openOrCreateDatabase(uri.toString(), 0, null);
how does your uri look like? it should just be the name of the database not a path

Comment: simply what i have done is copy the files from drawable folder into sd card